# An unusual question to ask regarding the solution to a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The solution to the differential equation $60P'(t) = P(t)[12 - P(t)]$ with an initial condition $P(0) = 3$ is
\begin{equation*}
P(t) = \frac{12}{1 + 3e^{-\frac{1}{5} \, t}} .
\end{equation*}
The function is increasing on the interval $[0, \, \infty)$, and 
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{t\to\infty} P(t) = 12.
\end{equation*}
This is part a.) to a problem on a past AP test.

Part b.) directs students to find the "function value" when the function is increasing the fastest.  The solution provided says "half of the maximum value is when the function is growing the fastest, and lim P(t) = 12. So, when the function value is 6, the function is growing the fastest."  Apparently, there is some rule that can be implemented.  What is it?

I know that $P(t)$ is increasing the fastest at the time $P^{\prime}(t)$ is a maximum, and I know $P^{\prime}(t)$ obtains its maximum at a time at which $P^{\prime\prime}(t) = 0$.
\begin{equation*}
P^{\prime}(t)
= \frac{12 e^{- \frac{t}{5} } }{ 5( 1 + 3e^{- \frac{t}{5}} )^{2} } .
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
P^{\prime\prime}(t)
= - \frac{108 e^{- \frac{t}{5} } (1 - 3e^{- \frac{t}{5} }) }
{25 ( 1 + 3e^{- \frac{t}{5}} )^{3} } .
\end{equation*}
So, the only critical number of $P^{\prime}(t)$ is at $5\ln3$, and $P(5\ln(3)) = 6$.  This confirms the answer provided by the College Board.

What is the rule, and to what kind of differential equation can the rule be used?

Comment: Once you've obtained a twice differentiable function $P(t)$ (in this case, by solving a differentiable equation, but in general doesn't matter how), its points of fastest growth can be sought by solving $P''(t) = 0$ and checking the sign of $P'(t)$ at those solution.

Comment: @avs  That is what I did.  The solution provided indicates that there is a faster way to do it.

Comment: Yes, the answer from Semiclassical does provide a faster way, using the structure of the ODE as additional information.  But, I was trying to answer your question (as I understood), and my point was that even if there is no additional information, you can still proceed the way you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to differentiate, nor to solve the differential equation for this. You already know that $$P'=\frac {P (12-P)}{60}. $$ The maximum of $P (12-P) $ occurs when $P=6$, because an inverted parabola [achieves its maximum in the middle point of its two roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2173823/22857). So the max of $P'$ occurs when $P=6$.

Comment: That is why they ask for the "function value" when the rate is increasing the fastest. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since $60P'(t) = P(t)[12 - P(t)]$, the function is increasing fastest (i.e. $P'(t)$ is largest) when $P(t)(12-P(t))$ is as large as possible. But $y=P(12-P)$ is the equation of a parabola, and its peak occurs halfway between its roots i.e. when $P=6$.